# Necessary condition for 3-CNF unique satisfiability

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat

I need to iterate through all formulas of 7 variables in 3-CNF which have unique satisfying assignment (1,1,1,1,1,1,1).

I could iterate through all formulas which are true under that assignment -- that is, all formulas with no clauses of sort (not a or not b or not c). But there are 2^(7*(7,3)) = 2^245 such formulas.

Are there any good necessary conditions for uniqueness of satisfying assignment that would help me iterate through less number of formulas?

Comment: This kind of problem tends to be (co)NP-hard.

Comment: Yeah but I don't need necessary *and* sufficient conditions. Just necessary conditions to reduce the number of formulas I need to look at.